# Android : Load images from external folder in Server

Tags: android, wcf, postgresql, android-listview, android-imageview

I am relatively new to android and I  am currently working on an android app that displays and stores profile information of registered users:

- The app communicates with a server using .Net(WCF) webservice and a
  PostgreSQL Database.
- In the Server(Virtual Machine), I have an existing folder containing hundreds of pictures(named after the username of each user). Example: A User login is Aadrian, then his picture is found in the folder under the name "Aadrian.jpg" in the folder.

  **Question:** I have a custom listview (with imageview and textviews) showing each user information and I would like to ask for help to know how to load these images from the folder in the server and assign each user in the list to his corresponding picture in the external folder. Kind of like how social apps like whatsapp and facebook do. Please let me know if I need to clarify any point more.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should try this Lazy-loading library https://github.com/thest1/LazyList and since you already know the file name, you should always be able to pass it directly into there and have it load for you.

Comment: I read about lazy-loading, but all the examples on the net specify an predefined array of links, but in my app I have around 800 images and  I would like to know how to go through(loop)folder search and compare the names of the image files with the userID and assign images to each individual appearing in the listview.

Comment: "A User login is Aadrian, then his picture is found in the folder under the name "Aadrian.jpg" in the folder." -- Technically you have all the URLs if you already have the users.

Comment: Yes but how do i go through a loop where the name of the images is a variable. Create a default string with hardcoded 800 links in it? I would like to find an efficient way to map the images to their corresponding users.

Comment: In your User object, why not just make a method getImageUrl() that returns a string:   return "http://your_url/images/" + userName + ".jpg";

Comment: Please, do you have a concrete example on how to implement this function? I am new to android and I am not sure how to do this.